# Is it possible to pass a parameter to iOS App Store which can be retrieved after installation of the app?

Tags: ios, installation, app-store, referrer

following situation: I have an app in the app store, where among other things, user can communicate with each other. In order to do so, they first have to connect to each other and confirm the connection. Now, I want to add an invitation functionality, basically:

- userA sends a link to website to newUser
- new user opens website, with a link to the app store
- new user installs the app
- a connection between user A and new user (now user B) is established.

In the conventional web-world I would have an invite link: [www.mysite.com?invitingUser=userA](http://www.mysite.com?invitingUser=userA) and I could evaluate it after sign up.
Is there something similar in iOS world, a way to provide the installed app with a parameter directly after or during installation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe I didn't understand everything, but I assume **Firebase dynamic links** could be something you are looking for?! Of course let me know if not, also interested in the possible way/solution. [Firebase dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create)

Comment: You can ask user to login and use those name. Or user with two phones (A and B for example) mast have two different userA and userB names? In such case you can use `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString`, or even better `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.hashValue`.

Comment: In your case what happens if user decide to re-login with a different username? Should parameter userA be the same as was received during installation?